I can't index to 0 in a python string inside a list using a function
I was using a function to calculate the standard deviation of some hashing methods and I can't seem to read the words from a list which in turn loads it from a file by indexing to first letter of the strings Here is the entire code:
import numpy as np
listhash1=[]
listhash2=[]
listhash3=[]
templist=[]
dictlist=[]
def hash1(list:list,list1):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        list1.append(ord((list[i][0]).upper())+len(list[i])-ord('A'))
    return list1
def hash2(list:list,list2):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        list2(((ord((list[i][0]).upper())-ord('A'))*len(list[i]))%100)
def hash3(list:list,list3):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        list3((ord((list[i][0]).upper())-ord('A'))%len(list[i]))
def variance(list):
    sum=0
    deviations=0
    for i in range(len(list)):
        sum=sum+list[i]
    sum=sum/len(list)
    for j in range(len(list)):
        deviations=deviations+np.pow((list[j]-sum),2)
    deviations=deviations/len(list)
    deviations=np.pow(deviations,0.5)
    return deviations
q=0
with open("dict.txt","r") as dictionary:
    for line in dictionary:
        dictlist.append(dictionary.readline())
listhash1=hash1(dictlist,templist)
listhash2=hash2(dictlist,templist)
listhash3=hash3(dictlist,templist)
print(variance(listhash1),"\n",variance(listhash2),"\n",variance(listhash3),"\n")

Sorry for any lack of specificty, this is my first question on this site
Edit: To expand further, when I try to run it, I get an error saying invalid string index on line 9(ord(list[i][0]), I tried running it with index 1 for the string instead of 0 since it wouldn’t really impact the hash function but it still didn’t change the error
Edit 2: the issue was fixed after I tried all suggestions in the comments. If for reference purposes anybody wants the results of the program, here they are:
7.631627233244063,
28.864721512130362,
2.8228899955211144

There are numerous problems here. Numpy has no pow function, but power. Lists are not functions, yet you call them as functions, probably forgetting you wanted to call append. You shouldn't shadow the native list function. Your functions don't return anything, yet you use their return values as if they are lists. All these are mistakes you would easy spot if you would just run your code with a debugger, and if you would use a good IDE which would warn you about several of these issues.

The list of words will always contain at least one empty string (the last line), which accounts for the index-error. But there are many other problems with the script, as already pointed out above. To fix the one problem you asked about, read the list of words like this: with open("dict.text") as file: dictlist = file.read().split().

for line in dictionary: loops over the lines in the file. Then dictionary.readline()) reads the next line in the file. Just use line, there's no need to call readline().

It seems that you're not actually deserializing the dict object but just reading it (line by line) as a file:
with open("dict.txt","r") as dictionary:
    for line in dictionary:
        dictlist.append(dictionary.readline())

You could try something like:
import ast
with open("dict.txt","r") as dictionary:
    dictlist = ast.literal_eval(dictionary.read())

This is an educated guess of what you're looking to do. But somehow you need to get the file object (or text) into the python object (dict).

There's nothing in the code that suggests that the elements of dictlist should be dictionaries.
